# how to get the arima model's variance of white noise's at each points in R?

Tags: r, statistics, forecasting

I have trained a ARIMA(1,0,2)(0,1,1)[7] just like that:(use R's function Arima{forecast} )

```
 >test.arima=Arima(x=tsx.rd_lm, order=c(1,0,2), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=7),fixed=c(NA,0,NA,NA), lambda=0.9533674)

 >test.arima
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0.9533674 

Coefficients:

     ar1  ma1     ma2     sma1
  0.6089    0  0.2314  -0.8650
s.e.  0.0426    0  0.0513   0.0383
sigma^2 estimated as 170690303:  log likelihood=-4908.65
AIC=9825.3   AICc=9825.43   BIC=9845.84
```

How ever, the sigma value {170690303} is terriable, so I hope get each points white noise (variance) to check. After all, maybe some xreg parameter could be find more effectivly. 
@ADD: a brief of the data:`Named num [1:241] 732499 724785 717221 709805 702539 ...`
@ADD: how ever, `test.arima` doest't offer the names like a `lm` class in R. 
So, just like get the lm model's residuals at each point by residuals `lm.my$residuals`, How to get the arima class's white noise's at each points in R?

Thanks!

Comment: @ADD the order of arima is currently tried best.

Comment: Not really a coding question. The test I use for that decision is: "Is it clear that the questioner knows what the theoretical answer should be?". If it's not clear then its's not a coding question but rather a statistical education request.

Comment: Please use the edit function when it seems you left something out of your origianl question. Adding a comment is both ineffective and in this case is incoherent. You own that question.

Comment: maybe I should use a garch to fit the variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
residuals(test.arima)
```

However, you should be aware that the size of $\sigma^2$ depends on the scale of the data. Divide your data by 1000, and your $\sigma^2$ value will be 170.690303.

Comment: One more question confused me. For a simple model like AR(1,0): Y(t)=e(t)-beta*e(t-1), if the training result is  $\sigma^2$/data_size=10, does it means e(t)'s variance is 10?

Comment: By "scale of the data", I do not mean the number of observations. I mean the variance of the data. $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the residuals which is proportional to the variance of the data.